# Spreadsheet IF Statements of multiple cells outputting string of text

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Hey Stackoverflow users,

I have a spreadsheet from a survey I conducted for one of my classes. A big chunk of my spreadsheet is columns of numbers; they represent "strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree and strongly disagree" and it's for personalities. I want to pick out certain numbers and see IF they are larger than 3 (neutral) and then output in a cell what that personality would be. If the number is less than 3 than it'd be some opposite personality.

I can provide an example with a picture if needed. My main question is...is it possible for a cell to collect data from different cells (not in a range) and output text in a single cell.

I've accomplished one personality.

```
  =IF(M3>3,"Disorganized","Organized")
```

The only problem is that I am not doing M3=3 is "neutral."

Then I want to do that for 4 other columns and put them all in one cell.

This is the gist of the personality stuff

```
  =IF(J3>3, "Creative", "Convential")
  =IF(M3>3, "Disorganized", "Organized")
  =IF(P3>3, "Introvert", "Extrovert")
  =IF(T3>3, "Rude", "Nice")
  =IF(V3>3, "Calm", "Insecure")
```

I want to get all 5 of them in one function in one cell and have a "both/neutral" output as well. So let's say one surveyee has 5,5,5,5 and 5, then the cell after all of them would say "Creative, Disorganized, Introvert, Rude, Calm." I hope this makes sense. Also, there are other columns between those specific columns.

Thanks for reading this far. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= IF(J3=3,"Neutral", IF(J3>3, "Creative", "Convential")) & ", " & 
  IF(M3=3,"Neutral", IF(M3>3, "Disorganized","Organized")) &  ", " &
  ...the rest of your formula here
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This did exactly what I wanted.